# Lebesgue Integral using Monotone Convergent Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let f be Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbf{R}$, and let $\epsilon>0$.Using Monotone Convergence Theorem prove we can find a compact interval [a, b] such that $\int_{R - [a,b]}|f| <\epsilon$

I try by build $f_n = f\cdot \chi_{[-n, n]}, f_n \rightarrow f$ but i am not sure how to continue. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Good start! If $f_n\to f$ pointwise, how are $\int_{\mathbb R} f_n$ and $\int_{\mathbb R} f$ related?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_R f_n = \int_R f$

Comment: Can we use LDCT?
Let $f_n= f \cdot \chi_{[-n, n]}$, then $f_n \rightarrow f \text{ and } |f_n|\leq |f|$.
By LDCT:
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_R f_n = \int_R f$
or
$\int_R |f \cdot \chi_{[-n, n]} - f| \rightarrow 0 \ \ i.e. \int_{R \cap [-n, n]^c } |f| \rightarrow0$
thus exists $N$ such that $\int_{R \cap [-n, n]^c} |f| <\epsilon$ for $n>N$

Comment: Applying dominated convergence to the modulus is easier; it yields $$\lim_n \int |f_n| = \int f.$$ (Note that $\lim_n \int f_n = \int f$ does in general not imply this statement.)

Comment: **Suggestion**: Define $f_n = \vert f \vert \cdot \chi_{[-n, n]}$. Then $f_n \rightarrow \vert f \vert$ monotonically.  Now, applying the Monotone Congence Theorem, we get that $$\int_{[-n,n]} \vert f \vert = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f_n \vert \to \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f \vert $$
Since $f$ is integrable, we know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f \vert < +\infty$, so we have 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-n,n]} \vert f \vert = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f \vert - \int_{[-n,n]} \vert f \vert \right) \to 0  $$
Then the result follows immediately.